# GPU activating problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have switched to Ubuntu for some reasons(Dual boot with win10).
 But my computer doesn't see my GPU anymore.
I have done some codes and changed settings of the additional drivers too but it haven't worked. (language isn't important)

[image: For info click here!]

[image: For more info click here]

[image]

Comment: [More info](https://i.imgur.com/xxzsEe2.png)

Comment: please put terminal commands and/or output as text into your question instead of making image screenshots. This makes it much easier for people to read it.